# Is it possible to load and manipulate HTML DOM without using UI/WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, html, swift, dom

- It looks like SwiftSoup is not actively maintained.
- It looks like I can use JSContext for evaluating JavaScript but I don't know how to
  use with a HTML DOM.
- UIWebView is no longer supported.
- WKWebView has some foreground requirements. And I have to load an entire web page
  which can take a while.
- I have existing JavaScript so it would be nice to reuse it.

What can I do if I want to manipulate the DOM without bumping into WKWebView constraints?

Comment: You can't have a true DOM without a browser context - which requires a heavy-lifting engine like WebKit. When you say "DOM" do you really mean you want to manipulate markup and/or traverse a HTML document's structure (and not "load" a page, run embedded JavaScript, download images, etc)?

Comment: @Dai. That makes sense. Yes, I want to manipulate the DOM for the purpose of understanding it and extracting from it. Images and other files are not required.